# Could I change the order and format of field with aggregate function in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to change the order of result and the format as well.
The format is just like Findone(); however, I want to use aggregate function in my code. Thank you!!

My current code is like this.

```
db.zips.aggregate(
{$project:{ city: 1, loc: 1, pop: 1, state: 1, _id: 1}},
{$sort:{ state:1, city:1}}
)
```

**Current Result**
[image: Current Result]

**Goal**
[image: Goal]

Comment: What are the changes you need to have on the goal over current result. To have only one document ?

Comment: Please correct your Code Tag and explain why you want to sort. Also i can't identify a formating difference between the both BSON objects (eycept the space)

Answer (score 0):

[BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) is a representation of [JSON](http://json.org).

There is no need for changing the sort of the documents properties.
So no, there is no aggregate function to accomplish this.

You have to go on your own. While a simple loop would have the same problem, for this small document, you can access the properties separately.

Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key) and its comments (related questions).

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is soley the Aggregation, you don't need to change the order of the document, you can just use the aggregate function as needed